# Fluent Nhibernate Decimal Primary key with Auto Increment

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

Is it Possible to created Decimal as a Primery key with Auto Incremented from FNH Mapping??

Comment: `System.Decimal` or `DECIMAL(x,0)`? (I don't know why one would want the former as an auto-incremenet and the latter can generally be written in terms of a standard integral type.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve auto increment Identity type must be integral int, long, uint, ulong.

ex :

public class User
{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual IList Names { get; set; }
}

Id(x => x.ID).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Increment();

for decimal properties : 
Id(x => x.ID).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Assigned();

Assign the value while creating a new object. Value should be increment of last generated key in your database.

OR you can just implement a Custom ID Generator for NHibernate.
http://lucisferre.net/2009/07/14/implementing-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate/

Comment: The question is about "decimal" (fsvo) and auto-increment; possible or not? (As shown, an integer PK can be auto-increment and a PK can be explicitly assigned.)

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same thing. It appears that `fluent-nhibernate` is [enforcing this constraint](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/b8aa3ea394504af2ed7f00ef287699ca07410f82/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/GeneratorBuilder.cs#L73).

If you know that the database will allow this (in this case, it should be fine) you can just bypass the constraint like so:

```cs
Id(x => x.MyDecimalId).GeneratedBy.Custom<IdentityGenerator>();
```

This will use the same strategy as `Identity()` would have, but not raise an exception. In my case, I've added an extension method on `IdentityGenerationStrategyBuilder<IdentityPart>` as such:

```cs
public static class IdentityPartExtensions
{
    public static void NumericIdentity(this IdentityGenerationStrategyBuilder<IdentityPart> identityBuilder)
    {
        identityBuilder.Custom<IdentityGenerator>();
    }
}
```

So then you can just do:

```cs
Id(x => x.MyDecimalId).GeneratedBy.NumericIdentity();
```